# Spinner inside Modal while waiting for Data to Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of items that each have a badge attached to them.  When you click the badge it will load a table from a partial view.

This is my Loop for the Badges:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
        <li>
            <a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="@Url.Action("AssociatedToHideout", "Hideout", new { id = item.HideoutID })">
                <span class="badge-rounded bg-red">@Html.Action("TaskCount", "Hideout", new { id = @item.HideoutID })</span>                  
            </a>
            <div class="item">            
                <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Hideout", new { id = @item.HideoutID })'>
                    <img src="~/Assets/img/database.png">
                    <span class="caption">@item.Name</span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </li>      
}
```

That URL Action inside the data-book-id will tell me which partial view to load.

This is my Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script to load it inside the modal is this:

```
<script>
    $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');

        $.get(bookId, function (data) {
            $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body').text('');
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I first load the page sometimes the `.html(data)` won't display right away so I wanted a spinner to come up while it is waiting. How can I do this?

Comment: One solution is to hide an animated element (gif). When you click load the element is displayed. When the call returns you hide the element again.

Answer (score 0):

We use waitscreen.js.  It's very simple to use and [available on github](http://nodegame.github.io/nodegame-window/docs/lib/WaitScreen.js.html).  All you need to show or hide is:

```
//Show options
waitScreen.show();
waitScreen.show("Message");
//Then hide
waitScreen.hide();
```

And embed these at the appropriate place, which would be:

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
    waitScreen.show();

    $.get(bookId, function (data) {
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body').html(data);
        waitScreen.hide();
    });
});
```

You should also add some error handling because if any errors occur, the modal will never disappear...

Answer (score 0):

You can set a loding gif image as the content of `.modal-body` div before making the ajax call. When your ajax call gets the response from server, it will be overwritten by that response.

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
    var imgUrl="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif";
    var $loading = $("<img />").attr("src",imgUrl)

    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body').html($loading);

    $.get(bookId, function (data) {
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick in here is `data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"` by removing the default backdrop and create a dummy one by setting background color of the dialog itself with some alpha.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes: clicking on the background does not close the dialog as is expected.
solution: So to achieve that you have to add some java script code. Here is some example how you can achieve this.

```
$('.modal').click(function(event){
    $(event.target).modal('hide');
});
```